# Push Notification method in iOS Objective-C with FCM

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails-3, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

i`m wondering what method we can use in Xcode with Objective-C code to trigger push notifications in this function:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
// Print message ID.
NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);

// Pring full message.
NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

NSLog(@"Type: %@", userInfo[@"type"]);
}
```

note: i have try to trigger push notifications from Firebase Console and it succeeded, i got the the push notifications,

but now i`m trying to send push notifications from my backend server (Rails), using https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm

i got the data when i send notifications from my backend server, but i`m confused to handle data from my backend server to trigger the push notifications in  iOS, what method can i use?

Edit: i can get notification with this code in didReceiveRemoteNotification

```
UILocalNotification* n1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
n1.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"John commented on your post"];
n1.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
n1.fireDate = [NSDate date];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:n1];
```

but now the problem is, the notification only appear when i open my application, can i make the notification appear when my iphone in the background or locked?

Comment: Could you specify what exactly you want trigger? And why that method doesn't satisfy you?

Comment: i want to trigger push notifications in my iphone when someone commented on my post for the example 'John commented on your post' , i can`t do that using Firebase console right? i should send data notifications from my backend server when the comment is created and i should handle it from Xcode

Comment: You are absolutely right - when you want trigger any event that happens on your backend - backend should send notification (doesn't matter how - directly establish connection with APNs or using FCM as an additional layer) - and after that in  most cases user receives notification. Application could run in foreground(that simply didReceiveRemoteNotification:completionHandler called) or it could be launched - that first called didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (where you should not handle notification, but prepare initial setup) and only that didReveiceRemoteNotification called

Comment: i`m on the right track right? i must the handle the data i got from my backend server, to send push notifications to my iphone, but i have no idea how to trigger the push notifications in my Xcode, i think i must put something in didReceiveRemoteNotification:completionHandler , but it is only worked when the application in the foreground right? not in my background.

Comment: It will work *any time* you get remote notification

Comment: what i`m missing now if it should trigger the push notification? i have tried the format like this, but it didn`t trigger the push notification:
fcm = FCM.new(ENV['FCM_KEY'])
options = {data: {aps: {alert: "push notif message",sound:"default"}, priority: 'high'}
response = fcm.send(registration_ids, options)

Comment: Any time notification will raise - method didReceiveRemoteNotification:completionHandler will fired. If app isn't running - you will receive standard notification in system, that is allowed to app. Otherwise, don't forget to register your device for notifications and use real device instead of simulator.

Comment: i`m using the real device ( iphone ), i have registered my device, and i have got push notifications if i`m using Firebase Console

Comment: the problem is i didn`t get the push notifications when i send from my backend server, but now i get the solution, 
i must set the additional params in my backend server
      options[:notification] = {}
      #options[:notification][:title] = 'title of push notif'
      options[:notification][:body] = 'push notif message'
      options[:content_available] = true
      options[:notification][:sound] = "default"

Comment: You are well done. Hope I help you a little ;) Care about pitfalls, one of them is limited size of notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution! just add this option params in my rails

```
  options[:notification] = {}
  options[:notification][:title] = 'title'
  options[:notification][:body] = 'Calvin Sugianto vote on your post'
  options[:content_available] = true
  options[:notification][:sound] = "default"
```

before this code

```
  response = fcm.send(registration_ids, options)
```

Comment: @SivaSankar it contains data you would like to send for push notifications like this:

`fcm.send(ios_device_id, options)`